# Rails: Include External JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I want to use a JavaScript library such as a jQuery plugin. Do I use the Rails asset pipeline? Or should I include it with a javascript_include_tag? What are my options and what is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Will you use the JavaScript library on only a few pages or throughout  the application? If you will use it throughout the application, use the asset pipeline by adding it to the *vendor/assets/javascripts* folder. If you plan to use the library on a single page, use the `javascript_include_tag`.

Here are rules of thumb to guide your use of JavaScript in Rails:

- Logically organize your site-wide scripts in the *app/assets/javascripts/* folder.
- Copy external JavaScript libraries (such as jQuery plugins) to the *vendor/assets/javascripts* folder.
- List site-wide scripts in the *app/assets/javascripts/application.js* manifest.
- Let the Rails asset pipeline combine them all in one minimized *application.js* file.
- For scripts that are used on a few pages that have few visits, load as page-specific JavaScript.
- Put page-specific JavaScript in the *lib/assets/javascripts* folder.

For page-specific JavaScript, use `<%= yield(:head) %>` in the application layout and `<% content_for :head ... %>` in the view.

For a full explanation with all the details, see my article:

> **[Including External JavaScript Files in Rails](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-javascript-include-external.html)**

Comment: page-specific js should go in app/assets/, organized with the same directory structure as your views.  lib/ is nominally for assets shared across applications

Answer (score 3):

To access Javascript on a single file, `javascript_include_tag` is the best option.

With that what you can do is too add '`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( yourfilename.js )`' to your '`config/initializers/assets.rb`' file.

Answer (score 1):

In Haml

```
= javascript_include_tag "example"
```

To load the file `assets/javascripts/example.js`