# script src doesn't appear to load external js file in my Rails html view

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

If I use script tags with my code in it at the bottom beneath the closing body tag the javascript executes like it should. However I want to write many functions for other things to happen on the page and so it gets busy if I do it all on script tags, which is why I want separate external files for where the code lives and then in the head tags invoke my code with script src, etc.

I am running rails 5.2.2 and it isn't loading my external js files at all. At first I thought maybe it was broken code but alas I can't even get a simple alert event to work so I know it's not the code and in addition my function works when I stick it in script tags on the html view. Help! I am sort of a nascent hobbyist programmer and not the best of googlers so any and all feedback is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <script src="edit_cp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

application.js file

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

edit_cp.js file

```
var editCoverPhoto = document.getElementById("cp_button");
editCoverPhoto.addEventListener("mouseover", showMessage);
editCoverPhoto.addEventListener("mouseleave", removeMessage);
var para = document.createElement("p");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Edit Cover Photo");
para.appendChild(textNode);

function showMessage() {
  editCoverPhoto.appendChild(para);
  para.style.color = "black";
}
function removeMessage() {
  editCoverPhoto.removeChild(para);
}
```

Comment: I think this might be helpful for your case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531783/rails-include-external-javascript

Comment: I didn't quite find a solution in that question thread but thanks for sharing. I am stymied becuase in earlier versions of rails and previous projects I've had no problem with this. I'm just trying to use a little vanilla js for page events like mouseover and mouseleave when you hover over an icon, a new dom element is created displaying a message of what action you'll accomplish by clicking on the icon, etc.

Comment: I understand. I couldn't find proper materials about Rails 5 on javascript.
One thing is that assets have their own path that is generated by sprockets-rails.
For example 

`asset_path 'edit_cp.js'` 

will return the right path for url with something like  `/assets/edit_cp-60aa4fdc5cea14baf5400fba1abf4f2a46a5166bad4772b1effe341570f07de9.js`

This is where I've got this example:

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path

Comment: right. I put the file in the correct path: app/assets/javascripts/edit_cp.js

Comment: Alright... Now you can try to add like this
<script src="<%= asset_path 'edit_cp.js' %>"></script>

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a go tomorrow. I feel like that's redundant telling rails to look for the path when it already should do that lol but you might be onto something. If it works, I'll let you know and you can turn your comment into an answer which I'll in turn mark the question as answered

Comment: I understand.. No problem, take your time :)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! At first it didn't work when I tried to load the script in the head tags but then I just moved it to after the body close tag and my javascript ran like it should.

Comment: Great that you managed to make it work :) Keep it up!

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. I was seriously beginning to question everyhing lol ;) coding is fun....